# Application tried to present modally an active controller crash

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiviewcontroller, crash

I get that error only on hocky app and i cannot reproduce it
ItemsViewController not presented modally and it's invoked always using [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"show-items" sender:self];
any help the crash occurs alot.

```
Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <ItemsViewController: 0x128e046f0>.'

Last Exception Backtrace: 0   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018353edb0 __exceptionPreprocess + 124 1   libobjc.A.dylib     0x0000000182ba3f80 objc_exception_throw + 52 2   UIKit                 0x0000000188a1efb4 -[UIViewController
_presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4992 3   UIKit                                0x0000000188a21890
-[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 468 4   UIKit                                0x00000001887973cc
-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 180 5   UIKit                                0x0000000188cf5a98
-[UIPreviewInteractionController startInteractivePreviewAtLocation:inView:] + 1636 6   UIKit            0x0000000188cf600c -[UIPreviewInteractionController startInteractivePreviewWithGestureRecognizer:] + 132 7   UIKit         0x0000000188cf7084 -[UIPreviewInteractionController
_handleRevealGesture:] + 96 8   UIKit                                0x0000000188c2df30 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 160 9   UIKit                                0x0000000188842728
_UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 168 10  UIKit                                0x00000001886cf7a0 -[UIGestureRecognizer
_updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 780 11  UIKit                                0x0000000188c2f530 ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke898 + 68 12  UIKit                                0x000000018868e4d8
_UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 368 13  UIKit                                0x000000018868b254
_UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 2400 14  UIKit                                0x00000001886cd610 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1128 15  UIKit 0x00000001886ccc0c -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 760 16  UIKit              0x000000018869d04c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 244 17  Q8ForSale     0x0000000100685250 -[IBGMethodSwizzler sendEvent:] + 340 18  UIKit     0x000000018869b628 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6564 19  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001834f509c
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20 20  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001834f4b30
__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 536 21  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001834f2830 __CFRunLoopRun + 720 22  CoreFoundation             0x000000018341cc50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 380 23  GraphicsServices     0x0000000184d04088 GSEventRunModal + 176 24  UIKit                     0x0000000188706088 UIApplicationMain + 200 25  Q8ForSale               0x00000001000ba8f4 main (main.m:14) 26  libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000182fba8b8 start + 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the some source code snippets and the segue configurations it is hard to tell what is going on.
One source of the problem that there might be an attached action to the gesture/button that do the model presentation action in the interface builder.